# How can I continue a unit test after an assert fails?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

I want to execute the second assert in testIdPropery, regardless of whether the first one passes or not. How can I do this without putting a try/except block around the first assert? Here is the code:

```
class BlockTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.city1 = City(1, "New York")
        self.city2 = City(2, "Boston")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.city1 = None

    def testIdProperty(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, self.city1.id_city, "Assertion Error!") #This assert might fail
        self.assertEqual(2, self.city2.id_city, "Assertion Error!") #Execute this anyway

    def testIdGetter(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, self.city1.get_id_city(), "Error!")
```

Currently, if the first assert fails, the test case immediately reports failure, and the second assert is never run.

Comment: If you don't care about `self.city1.id_city`, but only `self.city2.id_city` in that test case, why don't you remove the line `self.assertEqual(2, self.city1.id_city, "Assertion Error!")` ?

Comment: I delete a few lines before i type here... i fix now!

Comment: To OP, why do you want to pass a failed assertion? If so why do you even need an assertion?

Comment: I need to execute all the asserts, and catch all asserts errors. I want to make like try, except, but i need to know if the uinitest have a method.

Comment: I think you want that line to be `self.assertEqual(1, self.city1.id_city, "Assertion Error!")`

Comment: Why catch the failing asserts? you don't want to know which tests have failed?

Comment: @Natercat no, i make a fail, i don't want to fix it.

Comment: @fips i want to execute all assert, for now i don't need to know who is failed

Comment: After reading this discussion, it seems clear to me what OP is asking: "How can I make a test case execute a series of asserts and report any and all failures that result, instead of stopping execution the first time an assertion fails?"

Comment: @Edward yes, that i need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your test it seems you are trying to test the `id` property of class `City`. So you can test those two instances you defined at `setUp` have a correct value set - similar to what you did:

```
def testIdProperty(self):
    self.assertEqual(1, self.city1.id_city, "Fail if City1 does not have id 1")
    self.assertEqual(2, self.city2.id_city, "Fail if City2 does not have id 2")
```

Now when you run this test it should pass. If some day you break your code and one of these two asserts fails, you want to see it when you run your tests and fix it.

But, if for some reason you don't want these asserts to fail temporarily until you come back to finishing up the test later, then you can skip that test like this:

```
@unittest.skip("skip this test im not done writing it yet!")
def testIdProperty(self):
    self.assertEqual(1, self.city1.id_city, "Fail if City1 does not have id 1")
    self.assertEqual(2, self.city2.id_city, "Fail if City2 does not have id 2")
```

**EDIT**: OK if you want to suppress errors from failing asserts don't do a try/except in every place you need it. It's better to write a generic function outside your test class:

```
def silent_assert(func, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as exc:
        print exc.message
```

And have this call your assert, so it will run the code and only print the error silently if it fails:

```
def testIdProperty(self):
    silent_assert(self.assertEqual, 1, self.city1.id_city, "City1 does not have id 1")
    silent_assert(self.assertEqual, 2, self.city2.id_city, "City2 does not have id 2")
```

You will be able to call any asserts on it and pass any number of arguments each one accepts. Not sure if it's a good idea to hide errors like this, I never had to do it but that's just me, everyone has their organizational style!

Comment: i don't want to skip all asserts, i want to skip only one assert(who is failed)

Comment: What about commenting the assert that fails, would that be an option? e.g. `# self.assert...`. If not why run it since you will not know/be able to see what happened?

Comment: I need to do something like this: `        try:
            self.assertEqual(2, self.city1.id_city, "Fail if City1 does not have id 1!")
        except:
            print("Assert Fail")
        self.assertEqual(2, self.city2.id_city, "Fail if City2 does not have id 2!")`

Answer (score 0):

What about using [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)?

```
def testIdProperty(self):
    with self.assertRaises(SomeError):
        self.assertEqual(2, self.city1.id_city, "Assertion Error!")
    self.assertEqual(2, self.city2.id_city, "Assertion Error!")
```

Comment: What means SomeError?

Comment: Replace that with whatever error you're expecting that line to raise. (You could also replace it with `Exception`, but that's bad practice, as it could hide a bug getting introduced down the road).

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing multiple checks and you always want to run all of the checks, the simplest solution is just to break them into multiple tests and make each test case have only one check:

```
class BlockTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.city1 = City(1, "New York")
        self.city2 = City(2, "Boston")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.city1 = None

    def testIdPropertyCity1(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, self.city1.id_city, "Assertion Error!") #This assert might fail

    def testIdPropertyCity2(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, self.city2.id_city, "Assertion Error!") #Execute this anyway

    def testIdGetter(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, self.city1.get_id_city(), "Error!")
```